# Azure Application Insights Alert Emails

Tags: azure

Is it possible to include the stack traces and the http headers of an error that is sent to an email from a triggered alert? The use case is more so for convenience to avoid having to go to the dashboard to get a full diagnosis of the issue and instead only having to look at the email to get a good idea what went wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, it is possible.

When you create an Insights Alert, you could enable notify.

[image]

Comment: Hi, does it work now? Please let me know if you want more future help